# VBA to replace sheet reference in formula within specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not the most proficient with VBA but have managed to piece together the following actions:

1. Copy info from sheet in workbook that macro is built in
2. Paste info in different workbook sheet (serves as a template) and prompt input msg box to create new worksheet (copies template sheet and create new tab) with name entered in the input box.  Code below for this step:

   ```
   Function IsWorkBookOpen(name As String) As Boolean
       Dim xWb As Workbook
       On Error Resume Next
       Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(name)
       IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
   End Function

   Dim xRet As Boolean
   xRet = IsWorkBookOpen("Roadmap - Campaigns - Current.xlsm")
       If xRet Then
       ThisWorkbook.Activate
       Range("B4:B20").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Workbooks("Roadmap - Campaigns - Current.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Request Form").Activate
       Range("B7").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=False, Transpose:=False
       Else
       Workbooks.Open fileName:= _
           "C:\Users\CompanyName\Project - MM Team - MM Team\Roadmap - Campaign\Roadmap - Campaigns - Current.xlsm" _
           , UpdateLinks:=3
       ThisWorkbook.Activate
       Range("B4:B20").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Workbooks("Roadmap - Campaigns - Current.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Request Form").Activate
       Range("B7").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=False, Transpose:=False

       End If
   ```
3. Copy last row of data and insert new line with existing formulas/formatting into master tracking list that needs to update the formula sheet reference to the new sheet.

   ```
   Dim NewSheet As String
   NewSheet = InputBox("Please enter name for new worksheet")

   Sheets("Paste Request Form").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Sheets("Paste Request Form").Copy After:=Sheets(8)
   ActiveSheet.name = NewSheet
   ```

Where I'm getting hung up is the last step.  I cannot figure out how to update the sheet reference in the formula to the new sheet name from the input box.  I've tried a couple things that I've found on the internet but not been successful to adapt them to work.  Any help would be most appreciated!

There should be formulas to update in the newly inserted row of data.  Example of the formulas with sheet reference below:
=IF((VLOOKUP(C$3,'Tab 6.24.20'!$A:$B,2,FALSE))="","",(VLOOKUP(C$3,'Tab 6.24.20'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)))

I assume there has to be a way to define an object for the old worksheet string and replace it with the `NewSheet` string.

Forgive any misspoken terms, I'm self taught and not sure that I completey know all the appropriate vba terms.

Comment: So you want to replace "Tab 6.24.20" with the new name? You would benefit from reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

There are some reference like this one: [Variable sheet name in sumif formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039692/vba-variable-sheet-name-in-sumif-formula)

So without testing, something like this:

```
Range("A6:A9").Formula = "=IF((VLOOKUP(C$3,'" & NewSheet & "'!$A:$B,2,FALSE))="","",(VLOOKUP(C$3,'" & NewSheet  & "'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)))"
```

---

Or if you want to search in a specific area for the formulas and replace the previous worksheet name with a new one.

It will search for values between the apostrophes `''`. The sheetname `'Tab 6.24.20'` fulfills this criteria and will therefore be replaced.

```
Range("A6:A9").Replace What:="'" & "*" & "'", Replacement:="'" + NewSheet + "'", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```